# The minimum and maximum floating point exponent of a real number

Tags: fortran, gfortran

How can I get the minimum and maximum exponent for 32- and 64-bit real numbers? I am doing some work to avoid underflows and overflows and would need to know those numbers.

I would also need the base for floating point numbers.

Is it possible in fortran to get the equivalent of `ilmach`?

Comment: Please do not edit the question in such a way that invalidates existing answers. I have no idea what is `ilmach`.

Comment: It is the old Bell-Lab Port library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-zero reals, the numeric model looks like `s*b^e*\sum_{k=1}^{p}f_k*b^{-k}`.

To get the value of the base `b` use `radix()`.  The minimum and maximum values of the exponent `e` can be found with `exponent` combined with `tiny` and `huge`.

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real32, real64

print 1, "real32", RADIX(1._real32), EXPONENT(TINY(1._real32)), EXPONENT(HUGE(1._real32))
print 1, "real64", RADIX(1._real64), EXPONENT(TINY(1._real64)), EXPONENT(HUGE(1._real64))

1 FORMAT (A," has radix ", I0, " with exponent range ", I0, " to ", I0, ".")
end
```

Comment: I know that `exp (x)` computes the base e exponential of x. How does one get the base b exponential of x, here b is any number?

Comment: Note: `exponent` not `exp`.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`range()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANGE.html) returns the range of exponents. The intrinsic function [`huge()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/HUGE.html) returns the maximum allowable number for a given numeric kind. From that you can see the exponent too by employing a logarithm. See also [`selected_real_kind()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND.html#SELECTED_005fREAL_005fKIND).

The base for gfortran and other normal compilers is 2, but you can test it using [`radix()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RADIX.html). They may be some base 10 kinds in the future.

In the same manual I linked you will find other useful intrinsics like `tiny(), precision(), epsilon(), spacing()`, you can follow the links in "See also:".

Comment: Don't forget about tiny() - the smallest positive number available.

Comment: Any idea how to get the number of base-beta digits in the mantissa?

Comment: See the `precision()` intrinsic or read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format