# fortran floating point arithmetic

Tags: floating-point, fortran

I have a Fortran routine that computes the parameters of the floating-point arithmetic system. However, on my machine this ends up in an endless loop. But if I put an extra print statement in the loop, it will escape the loop. Does the print statement somehow force Fortran to evaluate? I'm using:

**in short**

`ifort (IFORT) 16.0.3 20160415`

```
oner  = 1._O
zeror = oner - oner
do
          it = it + 1
          b  = b * beta
          temp  = b + oner
          temp1 = temp - b
          if (itemp /= zeror) exit
```

end do

Witht this extra print statement it does not end in the endless loop:

oner

```
oner  = 1._O
zeror = oner - oner
do
          it = it + 1
          b  = b * beta
          temp  = b + oner
          temp1 = temp - b
          print *, temp1 - oner           <------
          if (itemp /= zeror) exit
end do
```

I compile the code with

```
ifort -parallel -openmp -O3 -xT -axT
```

**complete routine wih comments**

```
subroutine machr ( ibeta, it, irnd, ngrd, machep, negep, iexp, minexp, maxexp,      &
           eps, epsneg, xmin, xmax)
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! The routine computes the parameters of the floating-point arithmetic system.     !
!                                                                                  !
! Output parameters:                                                               !
! - ibeta (integer) - the radix for the floating-point representation.             !
! - it (integer) - the number of base ibeta digits in the floating-point           !
!   significand.                                                                   !
! - irnd (integer) - specifies if floating-point addition chops or rounds          !
!   appear.                                                                        !
! - ngrd (integer) - the number of guard digits for multiplication with            !
!   truncating arithmetic.                                                         !
! - machep (integer) - the largest negative integer such that                      !
!   1.0 + real(ibeta) ** machep /= 1.0.                                            !
! - negeps (integer) - the largest negative integer such that                      !
!   1.0 - real(ibeta) ** negeps /= 1.0.                                            !
! - iexp (integer) - the number of bits reserved for the representation of         !
!   the exponent of a floating-point number.                                       !
! - minexp (integer) - the largest in magnitude negative integer such that         !
!   real(ibeta) ** minexp is positive and normalized.                              !
! - maxexp (integer) - the smallest positive power of beta that overflows.         !
! - eps (real) - the smallest positive floating-point number such that             !
!   1.0 + eps /= 0.0.                                                              !
! - epsneg (real) - the smallest positive floating-point number such that          !
!   1.0 - epsneg /= 0.0.                                                           !
! - xmin (real) - the smallest non-vanishing normalized floating-point power.      !
!   of the radix: xmin = real(ibeta) ** minexp.                                    !
! - xmax (real) - the largest finite floating-point number.                        !
!   xmax = (1.0 - epsneg) * real(ibeta) ** maxexp.                                 !
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  use parameters
  implicit none
  integer  :: ibeta, it, irnd, ngrd, machep, negep, iexp, minexp, maxexp
  real(O)  :: eps, epsneg, xmin, xmax
!
  integer  :: i, itemp, iz, j, k, mx, nxres
  real(O)  :: a, b, beta, betah, betain, oner, t, temp, temp1, tempa, twor,          &
              y, z, zeror
!
  oner  = 1._O
  twor  = oner + oner
  zeror = oner - oner
  a = oner
  do
    a = a + a
    temp  = a + oner
    temp1 = temp - a
    print *, 'a', temp1 - a
    if (temp1 - oner /= zeror ) exit
  end do
  b = oner
  do


    b = b + b
    temp  = a + b
    itemp = int (temp - a)
    print *, 'b ', itemp

    if (itemp /= 0) exit
  end do
  ibeta = itemp
  beta  = real(ibeta,O)
  it = 0
  b  = oner
  do

    it = it + 1
    b  = b * beta
    temp  = b + oner
    temp1 = temp - b

    print *, 'c ', temp1 - oner
    ! itemp = int (temp1 - oner)


    ! print *, 'c'
    if (itemp /= zeror) exit
  end do
  irnd  = 0
  betah = beta / twor
  temp  = a + betah
  if (temp - a /= zeror) irnd = 1
  tempa = a + beta
  temp  = tempa + betah
  if (irnd == 0 .and. temp - tempa /= zeror) irnd = 2
  negep  = it +3
  betain = oner / beta
  a = oner
  do i = 1, negep
    a = a * betain
  end do
  b = a
  do
    print *, 'd'

    temp = oner - a
    if (temp - oner /= zeror) exit
    a = a * beta
    negep = negep - 1
  end do
  negep  = - negep
  epsneg = a
  if (ibeta /= 2 .and. irnd /= 0) then
    a = (a * (oner + a)) / twor
    temp = oner - a
    if (temp - oner /= zeror) epsneg = a
  end if
  machep = -it - 3
  a = b
  do
    print *, 'e'

    temp = oner + a
    if (temp - oner /= zeror) exit
    a = a * beta
    machep = machep + 1
  end do
  eps  = a
  temp = tempa + beta * (oner + eps)
  if (ibeta /= 2 .and. irnd /= 0) then
    a = (a * (oner + a)) / twor
    temp = oner + a
    if (temp - oner /= zeror) eps = a
  end if
  ngrd = 0
  temp = oner + eps
  if (irnd == 0 .and. temp * oner - oner /= zeror) ngrd = 1
  i = 0
  k = 1
  z = betain
  t = oner + eps
  nxres = 0
  do
    y = z
    z = y * y
    a = z * oner
    temp = z * t
    if (a + a == zeror .or. abs(z) >= y) exit
    temp1 = temp * betain
    if (temp1 * beta == z) exit
    i = i + 1
    k = k + k
  end do
  if (ibeta /= 10) then
    iexp = i + 1
    mx   = k + k
  else
    iexp = 2
    iz   = ibeta
    do
      if (k < iz) exit
      iz   = iz * ibeta
      iexp = iexp + 1
    end do
    mx = iz + iz - 1
  end if
  do
    xmin = y
    y = y * betain
    a = y * oner
    temp = y * t
    if ( a + a == zeror .or. abs(y) >= xmin) exit
    k = k + 1
    temp1 = temp * betain
    if (temp1 * beta == y) then
      nxres = 3
      xmin  = y
      exit
    end if
  end do
  minexp = - k
  if (mx <= k + k - 3 .and. ibeta /= 10) then
    mx   = mx + mx
    iexp = iexp + 1
  end if
  maxexp = mx + minexp
  irnd   = irnd + nxres
  if (irnd == 2 .or. irnd == 5) maxexp = maxexp - 2
  if (irnd == 3 .or. irnd == 4) maxexp = maxexp - it
  i = maxexp + minexp
  if (ibeta ==2 .and. i == 0) maxexp = maxexp - 1
  if (i > 20) maxexp = maxexp - 1
  if (a /= y) maxexp = maxexp - 2
  xmax = oner - epsneg
  if (xmax * oner /= xmax) xmax = oner - beta * epsneg
  xmax = xmax / ( beta * beta * beta * xmin)
  i = maxexp + minexp + 3
  do j = 1, i
    if (ibeta == 2) then
      xmax = xmax + xmax
    else
      xmax = xmax * beta
    end if
  end do
end subroutine machr
```

Comment: I've no idea the answer (and only partly because I don't know what `itemp` and `zeror` are) and could guess that it's down to side-effect and elimination, but if you want to understand the parameters of the numeric model, can't you just [inquire of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31292835)?

Comment: Please, 1) find a better title, 2) show how you compile the code, especially optimization flags, 3) show a complete code sample, we are missing definitions and initial values of your variables, 4) what does the code print?

Comment: It's possible that OP is unaware of the intrinsic functions that Fortran provides for figuring out the number system.  Functions that may be of interest include `radix`, `maxexponent`, `minexponent`, `range` `rrspacing` and several others.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete code

Comment: It is still incomplete BTW. Show the definitions. It should be compilable with `implicit none`.

Comment: As Mark says look at the intrinsics. I think `epsilon()` will be of interest in particular. Also `tiny()` and `nearest()`.

Comment: I think what mark said is excatly what this code does, only are those functions only available from fortran 95+

Comment: And that is a problem? Your code is not compatible with FORTRAN77 anyway.

Comment: Worth pointing out (maybe) that Intel Fortran v16 is not a Fortran 95 compiler, it's way more modern than that, somewhere between '03 and '08.

Comment: @Julian The critical loop is cleverly crafted, but its functionality may be defeated by compiler optimizations (especially at high optimization levels that play fast and loose with floating-point transformations). Inserting `print` can interfere with those optimizations and make the code functional again. Try compiling for strict IEEE-754 compliant floating-point handling (I think the `ifort` flag is `-fp-model strict`), or lowering the optimization level (e.g. to `-O1`) for this particular code; isolate this code into a separate file so changed compiler settings don't affect entire project

Comment: A complete working case would be needed, in view of the problem already pointed out of possible typo preventing loop exit test from updating, and the (buggy?) behavior of ifort interprocedural optimization of breaking options like -standard-semantics and -fp-model strict.

Comment: How does zeror = oner - oner differ from zeror = 0.0D0 ? Do you need to loop to zero, or just some place close to zero? And does close need to be greater than or equal to zero? or can |close| be close to zero?