# Floating point arithmetic in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I've inherited some Fortran code that I'm trying to make sense of. It uses REAL variables in many places that, I think, it shouldn't - but maybe I'm misunderstanding how this works in Fortran (as compared to C++ which I'm much more familiar with), hence this question.

So the variables in question are essentially 'categorical values', 'factors' or 'enums' depending on how you look at it/want to call it. They are of data type REAL and can only take on a finite number of pre-determined, integer values. So say variable a can only be of value 1, 2 or 3. These values are read in from external files; in these external files, they are represented as integers, so it's not a case of 'rounding issues in external data sources' or something.

However in the code, it never does a straight comparison, always a greater than/lower than check. So, instead of doing

```
if (a == 1) then
```

it does

```
if (a > 0.9 .and. a < 1.1) then
```

You can imagine that this gets very confusing/tiresome to read, especially when it needs to check if a value is one of multiple categories.

So I think this is a case where someone at some point heard 'never compare REAL values' (because of the nature of the finite precision of storing floating point values, this same problem exists in every programming language), but then didn't really understand when that applies (I guess the first error is that categorical values should have been represented as integer values but that situation is what it is for now).

OTOH maybe I'm just misunderstanding how REAL and INTEGER values are represented and work in Fortran? Could there ever be a case where

```
b = 1.5
a = REAL(INT(b))

if (a > 0.9 .and. a < 1.1) then
```

would make sense?

Comment: You're correct: "Never compare real numbers without a tolerance." 
 IEEE floating point numbers cannot be exact.  You can no more represent 0.1 exactly in binary than you can 1/3 in decimal.  Reals in FORTRAN are IEEE floating point numbers; very different from integers.

Comment: Fortran's real numbers follow the model form `s*b^e*\sum_{k=1}^{p}f_k*b^{-k}` for some parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293563/3157076)); integers modelled similarly.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase my question clearly enough - what I meant was, if I put only integer values in reals, can they be compared with == ?

Comment: @Roel, yes you can use ==.  If you have a REAL variable, it is likely a 32-bit entity with 24 bits of precision, so you can compare for equality against an integral value up to 2^24.  If you have a DOUBLE PRECISION variable it is likely a 64-bit with 53 bits of precision.  For DOUBLE PERCISION, you can compare for equality up to 2^53.  Why?  Because integers within these ranges are exactly representable in the floating point formats.

Comment: If the variable should, logically, only take on a certain set of discrete, predefined values, then it *absolutely* should have a type that embodies those restrictions -- integer at least, and an actual enum type if FORTRAN has them.

Answer (score 3):

ONLY in the case you're not performing any operation with the real values (just assigning a value and comparing equality with the same literal you assigned, with same kind parameter), you won't need tolerance.

The thing is, for a real variable a such as:

```
Real a
a = 2
```

You can be sure that

```
a == 2
```

Will be always `.true.` . But e.g., for another real value represented by b:

```
a  / b * b == 2
```

(Or any other operation) is not guaranteed to be .true.

Comment: Not even a - 1.0 == 1.0 ? Maybe I do misunderstand floating point representation then; how can it become anything else than a value represented by mantissa 1 and exponent 0? Can't all (small enough) integers be represented exactly by floats with exponent 0, and aren't addition and subtraction then always exact, too? (I've read the 'everything about floating point representation' paper several times over the years but I'll freely admit I lose the forest for the trees reading it)

Comment: It's not guaranteed in the general case. Yes, surely there are a set of values that this would stand true, but you can't rely on that: which are those values? What's the threshold upon this stop working? What operations (and with what values) wouldn't break that? How to check it at compile time or runtime?

Comment: One would still expect `real :: a=2; print *, a==2; end` to give true even when that `2` isn't representable: the same conversion applies for the assignment as for the test.

Comment: Yeah, i think you're right, @francescalus. I may undo my edit. I'd put the question like this: which operations (and with which operands) can be done on a real value for that the result's representation assuredly equals the conversion to real of the expected integer result?

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason the variable has to stay REAL then you may use
the intrinsic Fortran function NINT (nearest integer) in the comparisons:

```
if( nint(a) == 1 ) then 
....
```