# Fortran bit separation between fraction and exponent

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, if I set `rk=selected_real_kind(20)`
how many bits are reserved for the fraction and how many for the exponent?

Comment: This is not defined by Fortran, so please provide details on which compiler, computer, etc. you are interested in if you care about specifics.

Comment: It's up to the compiler implementer. All you know is that for this kind `precision( 1.0_rk )` returns at least 20.

Comment: And at a more practical level, `selected_real_kind(n)` simply returns an integer, it does nothing to reserve bits for anything. The value returned may be used as a kind parameter for a real entity, but could equally be an invalid number for that.

Comment: @IanBush, one doesn't know even that (`rk` is not guaranteed to be a valid kind number for `1.0_rk`, seeing as 20 is greater than 10).

Comment: If what you care about is more the properties of the model of real numbers for a given kind, you have various options like those shown in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31292835/3157076). Depending on what properties you need to know, there may be more suitable inquiries to make. Please explain in more detail what you are wanting to know. (It's a very rare case where knowledge of the number of bits used to store the exponent is useful in a Fortran program.)

Comment: @francescalus Ah, true. And the 20 > 10 comment has taught me something, thank you, up goat using the wonderful auto-correct I came across recently.

Comment: You are looking for `digits()` and `storage_size()`.  The former gives the number of bits in the significand of the Fortran numeric model and latter is the total number of bits.  Note, there is no accounting for a hidden bit.  For example, with default real kind and gfortran one has `digits(1.e0) = 24` and `storage_size(1.e0) = 32`.

Comment: Although @steve's comment is undoubtedly helpful and widely applicable, it should be noted that neither relationship is demanded by the Fortran standard. `digits` does say how many _digits_ are involved, but there's no reason that the number of digits is equal to the number of bits in the significand (and would be hard to satisfy for a non-radix-2 model). `storage_size` gives the _storage size_, but this isn't necessarily the number of bits used in the numeric model.